# Facebook's REST API facebook.auth.getsession() error 100: invalid parameter

Tags: facebook, rest

I searched google and found allot of posts, but I am still stuck with this.

I am using the REST server as followed:

https://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?api_key=xxxxxx&auth_token=xxxx&format=JSON&method=facebook.auth.getSession&sig=xxx&v=1.0

I know that all the values are right, because when I attempt to change them I get "Incorrect signature" error.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Used Graph API instead. I don't think Rest API is functional.